# Jquery Return value from.post is a bool but how to test the condition

Tags: jquery

I have some code like:

```
$.post('/Invoice/UpdateFieldUser/', invoiceLine, function (data) {
    if (data == 'false') {
        alert("An approver could not be updated");
    } else {
        var fieldlabel = $('#fieldapprovallabel' + invoiceLineId + '');
        fieldlabel.text($(".fieldapproverddl option:selected").text());
    }
})
```

UpdateFieldUser returns a boolean. I thought I could test the return value as above but it isn't working. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'false'` is a non-empty string which evaluates to `true`. Try using `false` (no quotes), or use developer tools (like Firebug) to inspect the value of `data` to see what is actually being returned.

Comment: `'false'` is a string - you want `false` ( i actually use `FALSE` to make it stand out & obvious it is a bool value)

Comment: @RozzA Personally I dislike capitalized identifiers... haven't capitalized boolean values since my days of C programming. ;) However, IDEs and syntax-highlighting editors usually make boolean values stand out from strings anyway.